# FastText: AttributeError: type object 'FastText' has no attribute 'reduce_model'

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I use FastText to generate the word embedding. I download the pre-trained model from https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html
The model has 300 dimensions but I want 100 dimensions so I use reduce model command but I got an error

`import gensim`
`model = gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format('cc.th.300.bin')`
`gensim.models.fasttext.utils.reduce_model(model, 100)`
I got `AttributeError: module 'gensim.utils' has no attribute 'reduce_model'`

Heres are the code from FastText docs

`import fasttext`
`import fasttext.util`
`ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')`
`fasttext.util.reduce_model(ft, 100)`

How to fix this error, I cannot find any docs for the new command.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `gensim.fasttext.utils` does not have a function `reduce_model()`, as the error message describes.

That's not a common/standard operation - it's just something the Facebook wrapper decided to implement. (It looks like it's using standard PCA on a tiny subsample of the vectors, per [source code here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/util/util.py#L114).)

Why do you want to reduce the dimensionality?

Note that you'll lose some of the model's expressiveness, and if you were able to load the model at all to do the reduction, it's not too big for your RAM. If your main goal is to save model size, there might be better ways, such as discarding more rare words, depending on your reasons.

If you absolutely need to perform such a reduction, some options could be:

- Do it using the Facebook wrapper, then save the results in a form Gensim can load.
- Reimplement the same operation for a Gensim model, perhaps using the FB code as a guide. (You'd have to make sure the Gensim model is updated in all ways that it considered the original dimensionality, which might be tricky – it's never been a goal or function of Gensim to enable after-the-fact model-shrinking.)

Comment: I need the reduced one for comparison purposes. But according to your explanation, I find the better way for the overall process without reducing the size. Thank you for your kind support.

Answer (score 2):

It does have a function to do so, it's just not being utilized correctly:

Adapt the dimension

The pre-trained word vectors we distribute have dimension 300. If you need a smaller size, you can use our dimension reducer. In order to use that feature, you must have installed the python package as described here.

For example, in order to get vectors of dimension 100:
Python

```
import fasttext
import fasttext.util
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
ft.get_dimension()
300
fasttext.util.reduce_model(ft, 100)
ft.get_dimension()
100
```

Then you can use ft model object as usual:

```
ft.get_word_vector('hello').shape
(100,)
ft.get_nearest_neighbors('hello')
[(0.775576114654541, u'heyyyy'), (0.7686290144920349, u'hellow'), (0.7663413286209106, u'hello-'), (0.7579624056816101, u'heyyyyy'), (0.7495524287223816, u'hullo'), (0.7473770380020142, u'.hello'), (0.7407292127609253, u'Hiiiii'), (0.7402616739273071, u'hellooo'), (0.7399682402610779, u'hello.'), (0.7396857738494873, u'Heyyyyy')]
```

or save it for later use:

```
ft.save_model('cc.en.100.bin')
```

Source: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

As to the response

> "Why do you want to reduce the dimension size"

Probably because the full pre-train model is a huge strain on RAM. This helps reduce that.